# Why does Z3 give no response on the following input?

Tags: z3

I originally posted the question as shown below the dotted line, but since then I have an even simpler example:

```
(declare-fun f (Int) Int)
(assert (= (f 10) 1))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

produces an interpretation for f as expected. However change the constant to anything but 10, and Z3 just spins the arrowhead a couple of times but then prints nothing!

--------------------------------------- original question -----------------------------

I tried Z3 on the following input and the arrowhead turns a few times and stops but Z3 prints or says nothing. Why?

```
(declare-fun f (Int Int) Int)
(assert (>= (f 1 1) 1)) 
(assert (>= (f 1 2) 2))
(assert (>= (f 2 1) 2))
(assert (>= (f 2 2) 2))
(assert (= (f 1 1) 1))
(assert (= (f 2 2) 2))
(assert (or (= (f 1 2) 1)  (= (f 1 2) 2)))
(assert (or (= (f 2 1) 1)  (= (f 2 1) 2)))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

I feel like I'm missing something really obvious..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am obtaining (using iZ3, Z3 unstable branch)

```
sat 
(model 
  (define-fun f ((x!1 Int) (x!2 Int)) Int 
    (ite (and (= x!1 1) (= x!2 1)) 1 
    (ite (and (= x!1 2) (= x!2 2)) 2 
    (ite (and (= x!1 1) (= x!2 2)) 2 
    (ite (and (= x!1 2) (= x!2 1)) 2 2))))) 
 )
```

Run this example online [here](http://rise4fun.com/iZ3/2Yz)

Answer (score 1):

I presume you're using Z3 on rise4fun? The version running there may be a little out of date. We have to manually update the binary there. If it doesn't reply, it's either because it times out, or because there was some other problem (e.g., segfault). It's quite possible that the version on rise4fun exhibits some bug that's already been fixed in other version of Z3 (e.g., unstable, iZ3, etc).

Comment: You are right, the examples in this post are correctly executed by unstable Z3 and iZ3.

Comment: OK that's good to know. Would it not be better to fix rise4fun? For many novices to Z3 that's their entry point, and I can imagine their puzzlement when they see this kind of behavior from Z3!